# How to pass cassandra function from python cassandra driver?

Tags: python, orm, cassandra, default, cassandra-python-driver

I have code

```
from uuid import uuid4
from uuid import uuid1

from cassandra.cqlengine import columns, connection
from cassandra.cqlengine.models import Model
from cassandra.cqlengine.management import sync_table


class BaseModel(Model):
    __abstract__ = True

    id = columns.UUID(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    created_timestamp = columns.TimeUUID(primary_key=True,
                                         clustering_order='DESC',
                                         default=uuid1)
    deleted = columns.Boolean(required=True, default=False)

class OtherModel(BaseModel):
    __table_name__ = 'other_table'
    name = columns.Text(required=True, default='')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    connection.setup(hosts=['localhost'],
                     default_keyspace='test')
    sync_table(OtherModel)
```

There is `now()` function in `cassandra`, which gives `current time` to create record.

I tried to create record with `INSERT` query.

```
cqlsh> INSERT INTO test.other_table ("id", "created_timestamp", "deleted", "name") VALUES (3c156369-6d71-40e2-933f-b48fdda7681f, now(), false, 'test');
```

But When I tried with

```
created_timestamp = columns.TimeUUID(primary_key=True,
                                     clustering_order='DESC',
                                     default='now()')
```

It gives error in validation.

I tried to override `TimeUUID` column, and return `now()` from `validate` function.

But it stuck in insert record.

```
2017-01-16 12:20:06 [DEBUG] cassandra.cqlengine.connection: INSERT INTO  test.other_table ("deleted", "id", "created_timestamp", "name") VALUES (%(0)s, %(1)s, %(2)s, %(3)s)
...
...
    result = session.execute(query, params, timeout=timeout)
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 1710, in cassandra.cluster.Session.execute (cassandra/cluster.c:30976)
    return self.execute_async(query, parameters, trace, custom_payload, timeout).result()
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 3343, in cassandra.cluster.ResponseFuture.result (cassandra/cluster.c:68510)
    raise self._final_exception
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid STRING constant (now()) for "created_timestamp" of type timeuuid"
```

I tried with direct insert query.

```
from cassandra.cqlengine import connection

if __name__ == '__main__':

    connection.setup(hosts=['localhost'],
                     default_keyspace='test')

    session = connection.get_session()

    insert_query = """INSERT INTO test.other_table ("id", "created_timestamp", "deleted", "name") VALUES (%(0)s, %(1)s, %(2)s, %(3)s)"""

    params = {'0': '3c156369-6d71-40e2-933f-b48fdda7681f', '2': False, '3': 'name', '1': 'now()'}

    session.execute(insert_query, params)
```

But this also gives same error :(.

Is there any way to pass cassandra function in `default` from `python` driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't like passing `now()` as a parameter.  I was able to get your (lower) code to work by removing `now()` from your `params`, and adding it to the query string in the VALUES clause:

```
insert_query = """INSERT INTO other_table 
    ("id", "created_timestamp", "deleted", "name") 
    VALUES (%(0)s, now(), %(1)s, %(2)s)"""

session.execute(insert_query, params)

...

aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROm other_table ;

 id                                   | created_timestamp                    | deleted | name
--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------+------
 3c156369-6d71-40e2-933f-b48fdda7681f | da509470-dcc9-11e6-b047-2ff6499dee60 |   False | name

(1 rows)
```

Comment: is there any way to use `cassandra python` driver ORM without direct `INSERT` query ?

Comment: @Lafada I found a couple of examples, but one was a client side `datetime.now()` in the code, and another doing a `uuid.uuid1()`, but it looks like you've already tried that.  I'll search around later and see what I can find, but other wise check through these docs and see if you can locate anything: https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/object_mapper.html https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/getting_started.html

Comment: Generally, ORM `column` has attribute to set value which will execute on server side, in our case, we want to execute `now()` function on server side. I tried to find same attribute in `cassandra driver` but, no luck yet :(

Comment: have you get anything to do this with `Model` ?